# Using git branch in environment variable in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, branch

I would like to customize one of environment variable depending on branch that is being build.

```
environment {
        CUSTOM_ENV='xyz_${GIT_BRANCH}'
    }
```

I'd like to get `CUSTOM_ENV=xyz_dev` for `origin/dev` and `CUSTOM_ENV=xyz_master` for `origin/master`. Not sure if its important, but its multibranch project in Jenkins.

I tried things like `xyz_${GIT_BRANCH}` or `xyz_env.GIT_BRANCH`, but none of this worked out.

Answer (score 0):

If your shell happens to be compatible with `ksh` or `bash` then you can use the variable-expansion modifier `##` to discard everything up to and including the final `/` character, leaving get just the part of `${GIT_BRANCH}` that comes after that `/`.  That would look like:

```
CUSTOM_ENV="xyz_${GIT_BRANCH##*/}"
```

Note the double-quotes `"` rather than the single-quotes `'` you used in your question.  Single-quotes prevent the evaluation of variables inside the quoted string, and that's definitely not what you want in this case.

If your shell does not understand the `##` modifier then you'll have to use something like `sed` to get just the last part of `${GIT_BRANCH}`.  That would look like this:

```
CUSTOM_ENV="xyz_$(echo ${GIT_BRANCH} | sed -e 's@.*/@@')"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing a substitution in jenkinsfile for a variable. It should always be in `""`. From environment directive , I guess you are using pipelines. So, you can leverage the groovy syntax to achieve string manipulation.
Something like,

```
environment {
        GIT_BRANCH = 'orgin/master'.split('/')[1]
        CUSTOM_ENV="xyz_${GIT_BRANCH}"
    }
```